# Angular 6 - Form Validation on blur

Tags: angular6

I want to validate input filled in onBlur how can i do this. please help me.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="form" id="form"
                (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && onSubmit()"
                #f="ngForm" novalidate>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Social Id"
        [ngModel]="generalUserData.socialId" [maxlength]=12 name="socialId" [minlength]=10
        (blur)="onBlurMethod($event.target.name, $event.target.value ,generalUserData)"
        #socialId="ngModel" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.submitted && socialId.invalid }"
        pattern="\d{9}(v|V)|\d{12}" required/>
    <div *ngIf="f.submitted && socialId.invalid" class="invalid-feedback">
        <div *ngIf="socialId?.errors.required">NIC is required</div>
        <div *ngIf="socialId?.errors.minlength">NIC must be at least 10 characters long.</div>
        <div *ngIf="socialId?.errors.pattern">Not valid NIC</div>
        <div *ngIf="socialId?.errors.maxlength">NIC must be less than 12 characters long.</div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I used below sample [link](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/05/11/angular-6-template-driven-forms-validation-example) and then I want to validate as on blur how can I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I update code below like this

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Social Id"
    [ngModel]="generalUserData.socialId" [maxlength]=12 name="socialId" [minlength]=10
    (blur)="onBlurMethod($event.target.name, $event.target.value ,generalUserData)"
    #socialId="ngModel" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': (f.submitted || socialIdType.touched) && socialId.invalid }"
    pattern="\d{9}(v|V)|\d{12}" required/>
<div *ngIf="(f.submitted || socialIdType.touched) && socialId.invalid" class="invalid-feedback">
    <div *ngIf="socialId?.errors.required">NIC is required</div>
    <div *ngIf="socialId?.errors.minlength">NIC must be at least 10 characters long.</div>
    <div *ngIf="socialId?.errors.pattern">Not valid NIC</div>
    <div *ngIf="socialId?.errors.maxlength">NIC must be less than 12 characters long.</div>
</div>
```

now it is working fine.

Answer (score 7):

The `onBlur()` method has been changed since Angular 5. With template-driven forms you need to use the following syntax:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="lastname" [ngModelOptions]="{ updateOn: 'blur' }">
```

Here is the demo, hope it can help you :

https://codingthesmartway.com/angular5-forms-update/